# Hide a drawing if "false" in a cell google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to hide a drawing i made on google sheets only if the cell B42="Faux"
I already made some unsuccessful attempts and atm with the code i have it say to me : 'if is not defined' and i dont know why. I'm not a pro and i never went to any class about coding so all my knowledge on code is very basic if someone could help me it would be great. Here is the code i have :

```
function cacher1() {
  var student = {};
  Logger.log(student); //{}
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ez = s.getRange('B42')
    if (ez == Faux) 
     student.Hide 
};
```

I apologize for my bad english

Comment: perhaps because the editor does not understand that this is an `if` statement (googlescript statements are case-sensitive) [Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Comment: Oh after your comment i tried to make it wrote "if" instead of "If" and it seems to have worked but now it says to me that "Faux" is not defined im searching on my own atm but your help is welcome

Comment: `if (ez == 'Faux')` _Faux_ is a string value, so it must be in quotes

Comment: I did that but now the problem is that it does not hide my drawings so i must have errors again probably on the var student i found that on internet but maybe thats not what i really need here, i need something to identify my drawing